# Compare keys of dictionary with values of another dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, both of type `Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>`.
I want to select the range of entries from dictionary 1 which match the values/entries from dictionary 2.

E.g. dictionary 1 has the keys `01, 01.1` and dictionary 2 has the matching values `01, 01.1.` at key `1`

First I get the entries from dictionary 2 at key 1 like this:

```
var dictList = (from entry in DbDict
                where entry.Key == id.ToString() // id = 1
                select entry).ToList();
```

I tried to select these via linq with something like this:

```
var matchingEntries = (from entry in ExcelDict
                       where ExcelDict.Keys.Equals(dictList[0].Value)
                       select entry).ToList();
```

and tried more along those lines, but it won't return any results.

How do I get the range of valuepairs from dictionary 1, whose keys match the values of dictionary 2?

**Edit1:**

```
Dictionary 1: 
Key     Value
01      "these", "are"
        ..., ...
01.1    "just", "some"
        ..., ...
02      "sample", "values"
        ..., ...

Dictionary 2:
Key     Value
1       "01", "01.1"
        "foo", "bar"
        ..., ...                
2       "02", "02.21"
        "value1" "value2"
```

**Edit2:**

Expected output:

```
"01", "01.1"
"foo", "bar"
```

**Edit3:**

Compilable input as requested in the comments. This is exactly the structure I'm dealing with:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>();

dict1.Add("01", new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "these" }, new List<string> { "are" } });
dict1.Add("01.1", new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "just" }, new List<string> { "some" } });
dict1.Add("02", new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "sample" }, new List<string> { "values" } });


var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>();
dict2.Add("1", new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "01", "01.1" }, new List<string> { "foo", "bar" } });
dict2.Add("2", new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "02", "value1" }, new List<string> { "02.21", "value2" } });
```

**Edit4:**

Sorry for the late response. Both Gaurang Dave's suggestion in the comments and the accepted answer worked for me. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Can you provide Dictionary sample data? and also structure of both dictionaries.

Comment: See edit in OP. I hope it's not confusing.

Comment: And what's your expected output in that example?

Comment: you need to flattern `List<List<string>>` into a `List<string>`.
With `SelectMany ` that will simplify your issue.

Comment: Why do the entries for key `02` from dict1 not show up in the result? This key is matched by the values of key `2` in dict2!?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider: I wanted to provide info on the structure itself. Since I select the entries from dictionary 2 with key 1, I would only get above mentioned output.

Comment: @MineR: I added the expected output in the OP.

Comment: To be honest: I would rather build dedicated classes for your structure and implement the needed functions and properties. This is usually faster and easier to deal with than fiddling around with nested Dictionaries and Lists.

Comment: @Robert: You're probably right. I will consider your suggestion for the future, but for now I'll have to work with that :/

Comment: Can you write a compilable input definition? Like `var dict = new Dictionary ...`

Comment: @arekzyla: Added in the OP.

Comment: It is never a good idea to use FooBar examples, because they could mean just about anything. It's still quite unclear to me what you want. I mean from your example, is all it's supposed to do is return the value for key=1 in Dict2?

Comment: It also may help to write a method which shows what arguments you expect with this, and what data type the output is supposed to be.

Comment: Why do you have `List<List<string>>` in the first dictionary? Why not `List<string>`?

Comment: How did you get `"foo","bar"` in your output when they are not keys in Dictionary 1? You definitely need to change all the "foo" and "bar" to unique values.

Comment: @MineR: Yeah, I can see why it's confusing. I made some changes in the OP. And yes, the desired output is key 1 in dict 2.

Comment: @arekzyla: It should be clearer now with the unique values.

Comment: @Allix Try this. Its working for the values you mentioned in OP. You can check this with other scenarios that you may have. Let me know whether it worked or not `string selectedId = Convert.ToString(1);

            var result = dict2
                        .Where(d2 => d2.Key == selectedId)
                        .Where(d2 => d2.Value.Any(d2lst => d2lst.Any(d2lst1 => dict1.Keys.Contains(d2lst1))))
                        .Select(d2 => d2.Value)
                        .ToList();`

Comment: Is the output correct? It looks like it isn't.

Comment: What does this mean in English: "get the range of valuepairs from dictionary 1" ? Your sample data has too many `...` in it to be clear. Provide real data.

Comment: How 01 matches with 1 but 02 doesn't match? It seems the expected result is wrong.

Comment: Also what's the rule when joining (matching) dictionaries. `"01"` is different from `"1"`. Do you want want to check the equality by parsing as number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote:

> I want to select the range of entries from dictionary 1 which match
>   the values/entries from dictionary 2.

From your output in Edit2, it seems that you want to take the *values* from Dictionary 2. You don't do anything with the *Keys*. Each value is a `List<List<string>>`. In your example all strings in the first list of the value with Key 1 have a corresponding key in dictionary 1. Apparently that is the condition to decide that the complete value is in your output.

The first list of the value with Key 2 has an element which is not a key in dictionary 1. Hence nothing of the value is in the output.

**Unclear**: what if the 2nd list would match instead of the 1st list?

```
Key     Value
3       "foo", "bar"
        "01", "01.1"
```

Should this also be in your final result?

**Unclear** Do you want as result a `List<List<string>>`, or do you want one big `List<string>` with all matching values? What about duplicate values?

Let's assume you only want to check the first List in your List of Lists:

We'll only look at the values from Dictionary 2, the keys are discarded. Then from every list in this value collection we take the first one (if there is one), and as a separate property remember the complete list.

Of course empty lists should not be in the end result, hence we keep only those that have a first element:

```
// Only use the values of dictionary 2:
IEnumerable<List<List<string>>> dict2Values = dictionary2.Values

// then for easy comparison extract the first list
var separatedFirstList = dict2Values.Select(listOfLists=> new
{
     FirstList = listOfLists.FirstOrDefault(), // this is a List<string> or null
     AllLists = listOfLists,    // original List<List<string>> where FirstList is the first
})

// keep only the elements that have a first list:
.Where(stringListWithFirstElement => stringListWithFirstElement.FirstList != null);
```

By now we have transformed your example dictionary into:

```
{
    FirstString = {"01", "01.1"},
    FullList =    {"01", "01.1"}, {"foo", "bar"}, {...}, {...},
},
{
    FirstString = {"02", "02.21"},
    FullList =    {"02", "02.21"}, {"value1" "value2"}, ...
},
{
     FirstString = ...,
     FullList = ...,
},
...
```

From this sequence we only want to keep those WHERE ALL elements in the `FirstString` are keys of `Dictionary 1`:

```
IEnumerable<string> keysDictionary1 = dictionary1.Keys;
var matchingItems = separatedFirstList
    .Where(item => item.FirstList.All(txt => keysDictionary1.Contains(txt));
```

You see the Where and the All.

Result:

```
{
    FirstString = {"01", "01.1"},
    FullList =    {"01", "01.1"}, {"foo", "bar"}, {...}, {...},
},
...
```

The one with `FirstString = {"02", "02.21"}` is removed, because not all elements of firstString where a Key in dictionary 1,

Finally: get rid of the FirstString:

```
List<List<String>> finalResult = matchingItems
    .Select(matchingItem => matchingItem.FullList);
```

Or if you want the result to be one `List<String>`:

```
List<string> finalResult = matchingItems.SelectMany(matchingItem => matchingItem.FullList);
```

TODO: consider creating one big LINQ statement. As the intermediate steps use lazy execution I'm not sure whether this will improve performance. However I'm sure that it will decrease readability.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for `join` using linq:

```
var result = from d1 in dict1
             join d2 in dict2
             on double.Parse(d1.Key) equals double.Parse(d2.Key)
             select d2.Value;
```

In above query, we are joining two dictionaries by equality of key (by parsing the key as number) and for each match we select the `Value` from the second dictionary as result of the match.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want:

```
var result = dict2
            .Select(kvp => kvp.Value)
            .Where(list => list.Where(l => l.Join(dict1.Keys, s1 => s1, s2 => s2, (s1, s2) => s1).Count() == l.Count).Count() > 0)
            .ToList();
```